# Laptop randomly turns off when unplugged (Windows 8.1)

Tags: laptop

I just installed windows 8.1 on my HP laptop and it started randomly turning off while it is unplugged. When it does so the battery is at 100% or near and also it didn't happen before I installed windows 8.1. Previously the laptop worked just fine with Windows 7. Please, help.

Comment: I don't know. I edited my post with more info. Check it.

Comment: What model is the laptop and how old is the battery?

Comment: Um, not sure how to see model on the laptop itself, but it says G62 if it helps. The laptop(and the battery) is at least an year old so there is that. I wonder why this issued wouldn't appear with windows 7. Maybe going back to it will be a solution?